# Como contar registos iguais numa uncia coluna e obter esse mesmo numero?

Tags: php, mysql

Exemplo da tabela:

```
| Ti | Orien      |

| ---|   JML      |

| ---|   JML      |

| ---|   RGM      |

| ---|   AAA      |

| ---|   AAA      |
```

Resultado exemplo: JML - 2
                   RGM - 1
                   AAA - 2

Answer (score 1):

Com o php5.5 pode combinar a função `array_column()` que extrair os valores de indíce e retorna eles como um novo array, com use a função `array_count_values()` que dira quantas valores iguais existem no array, as chaves são os valores do banco de dados e os valores são o número de ocorrências.

```
$arr = [['str' => 'abc'], ['str' => 2015], ['str' => 2015], ['str' => 'doge'], ['str' => 'wow'], ['str' => 'wow']];
$itens = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'str'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($itens);
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [abc] => 1
    [2015] => 2
    [doge] => 1
    [wow] => 2
)
```

Comment: Estava a pensar em algo como um Select Ti, count(Orien) as num FROM tabela".

Comment: @RuiManuelMartins , um `select Ti, count(Orien) as num FROM tabela group by Orien` resolve?

Comment: Não testei ainda. o meu código é este:

Comment: $query_b="SELECT * FROM `docentes` ORDER BY `docentes`.`NomeAscii` ASC"; 
$query_c= "SELECT Orientador, COUNT(*) AS numInstances FROM teses GROUP BY Orientador";

print_TD("<select name='orientadorisep'></option>"; // list box select command
echo "<option value=' '</option>" ."Convidar orientador";
foreach ($db->query($query_b) as $row)//Array or records stored in $row {
      echo "<option value=$row[CodDocente]>$row[CodDocente] - $row[NomeAscii]</option>"; 
      /* Option values are added by looping through the array */
     }
      echo "</select>";

Comment: Desculpa enganei-me.
o objectivo basicamente é fazer um dropdown list com a informação de uma tabela e depois ir buscar á outra tabela os registos que já tem mais de um.